# Linear regression using gradient descent: is the whole weight vector updated with the same number?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I'm using gradient descent with mean squared error as error function to do linear regression. Take a look at the equations first.
[image]
 As you can see in eq.1, the prediction is done with a bias term b and a weight vector W. Eq.2 shows the error function (MSE) while eq.3 shows the partial derivatives used to update the weights (eq.4). My question is, should all the weights in the weight vector be updated each iteration by the same number? It seems like eq.3 should return a single number; not a vector.

Comment: no, $\alpha$ can depend on the variable $W_j$, those values for $\alpha_j$ at each step are the main parameters you can play on to accelerate the convergence (see for example the [conjugate gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) to see  all the possibilities you have)

Comment: So the correct way to do this would be to have α as a vector; if it's a two-dimensional problem then α is a three dimensional vector with the entries α_b, α_w1, α_w2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the other previous answers are correct but I did not understand them.

Looking at the left hand equation 3 in the original post, $x_i$ is a vector and not a scalar which results in $dL/dW$ being a vector, not a scalar which I misunderstood at first. $\Alfa$ remains a scalar but the weights in the W vector are updated differently each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Equations are usually used in this form when you're working in a neural network kind setting, where the bias term is also a vector.

In the case of linear regression, since the bias term is a single scalar, a more intuitive way to look at these equations is to treat the summation like $\sum_{j=0}^{p}W_jx_{ij}$ by treating $x_{i0}$ as 1, and b as $W_0$.

Programmatically speaking, this translates to padding your data matrix with a column of 1's to the left. You'll find this being done often in a bunch of tutorials that walk you through linear regression!

This gets rid of the second gradient equation and reduces it to only updating W with each iteration. Hope this helps :)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. Even if b is included in W and the summation starts from 0 with x_i0=1 in the equations above, the question is still same. The result from the gradient equation is still a single scalar, while the weights are a vector, so should each weight be scaled with the same number or shuold α be a vector instead of a scalar as @user1952009 suggested?

Comment: It actually answers the question! I'll answer it in greater detail. 

You're correct in saying that it's a single scalar and not a vector. And when you re write the equations in the form I told you, you will see that each weight is updated by a different number. For each weight, alpha will be the same while the corresponding element of the loss vector will be different.

The equatio for the bias term will just be like the first element of this vector. That's like saying that you've taken a term out of a summation.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the result from the gradient equation(s) (eq.3) a single scalar, irrelevant of whether or not bias term is included in the weight vector? You're saying the the result of the left hand equation 3. is a vector, not a scalar, if b is included in the weight vector? How?